# Cocoa Webview: cannot display Yahoo mail

Tags: cocoa, webview, yahoo-mail

I have searched through Google and stackoverflow but had no clue about my problem.

I am helping users to check their Yahoo mail within my app using Cocoa Webview.

In Yahoo mail page: I can display welcome page, but after I enter my Yahoo account and click "Sign In", I am redirected to a page displaying: "You're almost there, but your web browser doesn’t support the newest version of Yahoo! Mail".

And below that message are 3 links:

- Firefox
- Internet Explorer (for Windows)
- Safari

I then click on Safari but nothing happens!

I tried to log in with Gmail and Facebook, which are absolutely fine.

Any reason that my Cocoa Webview cannot load Yahoo! mail page ? How to fix this problem ?

Note: If I switch my Yahoo mail account back to classic mode, then it works fine. ( ie, Cocoa Webview can display the mail page)

Thanks in advance,

Josh

Answer (score 0):

You can spoof using Safari so that Yahoo thinks it is Safari connecting, this may solve it:

```
webViewOutlet.applicationNameForUserAgent = "Version/9.0.3 Safari/601.4.4";
```

You can find the latest string from:

http://www.useragentstring.com